# Chat rooms in non-English languages

Tags: discussion, chat

Someone created a [Brazilian chat room in Ask Ubuntu](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9267/brazilian-users-of-ask-ubuntu). When questioned about the language, the room owner advised me to use pt-br for in-room conversations.

Is it OK to create a chat room for users of a certain language and have that language used for chat on that specific room? In case it's OK, what if there are two variants of the same language, as it is the case with pt (Portugal) and pt-br (Brazil)?

Comment: related, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136259/what-languages-are-we-allowed-to-speak-in-se-chat-rooms

Comment: Why the downvote? Isn't it a pertinent question?

Comment: Downvotes on meta are different from the main site.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine this would go against the whole philosophy behind SE, as they want all the discussions to remain as public as possible. Having non-english languages would prevent many users from participating in those discussions, so I don't think it is permitted.

Yet, if you do, count me in for a Portuguese room ;)

Comment: I haven't, some other user did. Yet, it's a Brazilian-targeted room, there's a difference between pt and pt-br, I updated that on the question.

Comment: No, you *are* allowed to have non English rooms, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136259/what-languages-are-we-allowed-to-speak-in-se-chat-rooms However, not many users here use chat, so I'm not sure you would get a lot of users.

Comment: That's nice to know! Thanks!

Comment: @Seth Very old topic, I know, but I found it when searching today, so updating with a comment for others who come across it.  *No*, the question you linked does *not* say that you are allowed to have non-English chat rooms.  Shog9 was very clear that, while it *may* be acceptable to *speak* a different language in a chat room, for purposes of moderation (and others) *"the majority of content in Chat should also be in English*" and that *"When there's any doubt as to the appropriateness of a conversation (for instance: it gets flagged) and it can't be understood, it should be deleted."*